# Why only my first Router render the component? Second router is not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

'When i visit "/shop/hats" it shows only blank page. No error i could see. **But when i put category component in 1st route, it works.'**

'shop component'

```
import React from "react";

import CollectionPreview from "../../component/CollectionPreview/collectionPreview-com"
import {Route} from "react-router-dom"
import Category from "../../component/Category/category-com"


const Shop = ({match}) =>  {
    console.log("Printing" + match.path);
    
    return(
        <div>
           <Route exact path="/shop" component={CollectionPreview} /> 
           <Route path="/shop/:categoryId" component={Category} />
        </div>
            
        )
    }

export default Shop;
```

'Category component which is not rendering. but when i use this component in 1st route, it works '

```
import React from "react";
import "./category-style.css";

const Category = ({match}) => {
    console.log(match);
    
    return(
        <div className="Test">
            <h1>Test</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Category;
```

'I even tried mentioning 2nd route as normal route (Without Param-route). No luck'

Comment: I hope you wrapped your `Shop` component with `BrowserRouter`. Just posted a solution, try that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49162311/react-difference-between-route-exact-path-and-route-path

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

//your code

return (
   <Switch>
       <Route exact path="/shop" component={CollectionPreview} /> 
       <Route path="/shop/:categoryId" component={Category} />
   </Switch>
);
```

For more details about when to use `Switch`, refer this: [here](https://dev.to/danhjoo7/using-a-switch-component-in-react-router-d2k)

Comment: Thanks for this. But still it doesnt work. It shows empty blank white page. Even console log is not printing up in Category component if tried accessing "http://localhost:3000/shop/hats" - this local address.

Comment: Then there must be an issue with the `Category` component. It would be great if you share your project's CodePen.

Comment: Do my Github link helps?
https://github.com/DilipAnthony/ecom-website.git

Comment: This must solve the Routing issue. But you need to debug your Components for rendering required outputs.

Comment: Thing is, When i use Category component in 1st Route, it works perfectly.  I got Struck.

Comment: Ohh, I haven't gone through your logic yet. But that's something you need to debug.
Check this, it might help: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58494905/react-router-id-as-parameter)

Answer (score 0):

you can try with `useParams()` hooks. like below

```
import React from "react";
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import "./category-style.css";

const Category = () => {
const {categoryId} = useParams();
    return(
        <div className="Test">
            <h1>Test</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Category;
```

Comment: Everything tried. Nothing works.
Only thing i found out is, issue is with Nested Route.